# Is there already a constexpr std::bit_cast to use with g++

Tags: c++, c++20

I wonder if there is a usable `constexpr` `std::bit_cast` or equivalent already for g++-trunk in c++2a mode. I need this for a compile-time-check.

Comment: No. It uses memcpy with renders it non-constexpr.

Comment: Clang has it: `constexpr auto one = __builtin_bit_cast(std::uint64_t, 1.0);`

Comment: Just grep-ed the gcc sources: not builtin_bit_cast

Comment: until now [only MSVC supports `std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)

Answer (score 3):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), `std::bit_cast` is not yet implemented in any major C++ compiler as of 2019-11-29.

Comment: Yes, not in an official release. But I'm willing to accept patches or other solutions.

Comment: @wimalopaan this table also track (to the best of its ability) features in upcoming releases and a quick godbolt check confirmed that. I'm not aware of any `constexpr`-ble way to implement bit_cast in gcc for generic types.

Comment: Clang has had `__builtin_bit_cast(type, value)` for a while, which is necessary to implement `std::bit_cast`

Comment: @tambre yes, as mentioned in another comment by Evg, but Clang is not GCC.